# How to add radio buttons in button group?

Tags: java, netbeans, jradiobutton, netbeans-7.2, buttongroup

After dragging and dropping button group in Netbeans 7.2, how to add radio button in that button group?

Comment: with code: `btnGroup.add(myRadioBtn)`. What have you tried?

Comment: Thank you. I was trying from GUI. Is it possible to be done via GUI? Above code works fine.

Comment: @MouseEvent: I think that he means from NetBeans' Matisse drag and drop code generation tool. Myself, I recommend that he avoid using that tool.

Comment: good question clearing basics

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's a `Button Group` field in the radio button's property. Set this value for each of the radio button that you want to add in the group to the button group's name.

Answer (score 6):

1. Drag a **ButtonGroup** from the palette and drop it on your GUI. It will show up under Other Components in the Inspector panel.
2. Right-click on it and Change variable name to something meaningful.
3. Now select a radio button in your GUI.
4. In the Properties panel look for the **buttonGroup** property.
5. Click the combo box next to it and select your button group.

Answer (score 3):

Click on the Button Group and then click anywhere in the design form.  Select all the buttons you want to group by pressing CTRL and the button.  Right click on one of the buttons and select properties.  In the ButtonGroup of the Properties, click on the down arrow.  Your selection of button groups should appear.  Left click on the one you want.

Answer (score 2):

In Netbeans 8.0.1, I use:

```
ButtonGroup bG = new ButtonGroup();
    bG.add(btn_1);
    bG.add(btn_2);
    bG.add(btn_3);
    bG.add(btn_4);
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Group it as suggested before
2. Rebuild the Project
3. After rebuild, you will see the common line:

[image]